# Why Nasadiya Sukta says even god himself might not know about creation?

Tags: rig-veda

```
 Then even non-existence was not there, nor existence,
There was no air then, nor the space beyond it.
What covered it? Where was it? In whose keeping?
Was there then cosmic fluid, in depths unfathomed?
```

Why is there so much uncertainty in it? also, Nasadiya Sukta known as Hymn of Creation. what does that mean?

Comment: The real question is not where creation came forth, but even the cause of creator God itself. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/36840/20089 .Hindu Puranas have created a looped paradox of Brahma born from Vishnu, Rudra from Brahma and Vishnu from Shiva or tridev from AdiShakti as Hindus ask too many questions, while non-Hindus are either atheists or silently accept Allah or Jesus as creator or forced to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Nāsadīya Sūkta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasadiya_Sukta) (after the incipit ná ásat, or "not the non-existent"), also known as the Hymn of Creation, is the 129th hymn of the 10th mandala of the Rigveda ([10:129](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv10129.htm)).

Brereton and Jamison in their translation to this hymn, say as follows:

> This is one of the most famous hymns of the R̥ig veda, and one of the
>   most significant for later Indian cosmogonies. Because it is elusive
>   and suggestive rather than directly narrative, it has given rise to a
>   wide variety of interpretations.

---

Though subsequent literature like brAhmanas, puranas, etc, tried to explain the process of creation, after deification of Gods took place, attributing either to prajApati, or brahma or Shakti, etc, it is the Rig Veda, which is the source for every type writings in subsequent literature.

The [answer](https://qr.ae/pNyT6b) is clear from the Hymn, as mentioned in the last mantra.

> He who is the Eye above, in the highest space. **He surely knows**.
>
> ….. or **if he doesn’t know**

---

The composer of this hymn is a seer or drastha.  We have to accept the seer's conclusion that **only the CREATOR** knows how the creation came into existence.

Comment: I never thought my religion is this much deep.

Comment: Forget religion. Think about yourself very deeply and logically and know your self first. then compare what you have learnt with what you study and read.