# Can someone refute or clarify the claims that these verses are Sciencetifcally Inaccurate?

Tags: puranas, science

Can someone refute or clarify the claims made by Ved ka bhed regarding

Linga Purana I.61.28-29,
Matsya Purana 123.57-58,
Vayu Purana I.50.63,
Brahmanda Purana I.2.21.8,
Vayu Purana I.53.61-62?

Brahmanda Purana I.2.21.8 In diameter as well as girth (Circumference), the moon is twice as much as the sun.

Vayu Purana I.53.61-62 The diameter of the Sun is nine thousand Yojanas. The girth of the Sun is three times its diameter. The width of the Moon is twice that of the Sun.

Vayu Purana I.50.63 The extent of the sun is nine thousand Yojanas. The girth or the extent of its disc is thrice its diameter. The lunar disc is twice the solar disc (in diameter as well as girth).

Matsya Purana 123.57-58 The diameter of the Sun is nine thousand yojanas and its circumference is three times that (2700 yojanas). The diameter of the Moon is twice the diameter of the Sun; its circumference is thrice its diameter.”

Linga Purana I.61.28-29 The diameter of the sun is nine thousand yojanas. The extent of its circular surface is three times that. The extent of the moon is twice that of the sun

Comment: Pls post the verses too if possible....it might be of great help!

Comment: @Rāmachandra I added those verses

Comment: There is nothing to refute. These values you posted do not agree with science.

Comment: I can understand your excitement but pls don't jump into conclusions so fast .. someone might still explain :D @Wikash_

Comment: moon is more powerful planet interms of size and energy inside human..  moon governs manas or mind.. whereas eyes are governed by sun.. you see on full moon and new moon days lunatics would go bersek so it onlys shows the effect of moon on human mind is twices that of sun in humans. It may be true also nuclear fusion requires enormous amount of pressure. if sun volume huge as we see in the sky than there will be no nuclear fusion at all. it will be black hole.. who measured going inside sun first? may be like gaseous gaint like jupiter

Comment: @Rickross Yes sure. If a good explanation is given I will correct my statement. For now my statement is correct.

Comment: No not correct because you have not verified if those verses are at all found in those Puranas or not .. if found you do not know if the translations given are correct or not.. the website Ved ka Bhed is well known to post nonsense about Hinduism .. so you being someone who is "trying to learn about Hinduism" should not trust them at face value :D @Wikash_

Comment: @Rickross Yes, you are right again. So assuming these verses and their translations are correct my statement is correct.

Comment: There's no need to refute anything. "The Smritis and the Puranas are productions of men of limited intelligence and are full of fallacies, errors, the feelings of class and malice.Only parts of them breathing broadness of spirit and love are acceptable, the rest are to be rejected. The Upanishads and the Gita are the true scriptures" - Swami Vivekananda. You can realise Atman, there is no need to believe in anything. Swami Vivekananda stressed on reason and experience not belief.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do the Vedas claim that Moon is farther from the Earth than the Sun?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23339/do-the-vedas-claim-that-moon-is-farther-from-the-earth-than-the-sun)

Comment: We're not supposed to talk about any conclusions of the application of the scientific method or of academia. We are only allowed to reference sacred texts, so the question should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I checked Vayu and Linga Purana. The claims made by the web site about these two are correct. The web site can't be refuted. I am posting some verses from the Vayu Purana. Read the translator's comment.

[image]

Comment: What do they mean by imaginary?

Comment: Probably they mean wild guess.

Comment: @Pradip Gangopadhyay In Hinduism we don't accept any one scripture to be the ultimate truth or something. In Hinduism we can find both Scienctifically accurate and innacurate things on same topic. If these verses are Scienctifically inaccurate then in some other scripture we can find Scientifically Accurate description of these things. This scripture can be Scientifically innacurate but whole Hindu Dharma can never be because we don't accept any one scripture to be the truth.

Comment: @Sam Why do you want to know about science from Hindu scripture?