# Does the puranas say that the moon is bigger than the sun?

Tags: puranas, science, astronomy, moon

Does Brahmanda purana 2.21.8 claim the moon is bigger than the sun in size
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc362839.html

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23339/24460

Comment: No the question is about the size of sun and moon not distance

Comment: Nope my question was about size not distance

Comment: ikr, but some answers do address that too. Your question isn’t duplicate. If you’re interested, you may check.

Comment: The moon being talked about here isn’t the satellite moon exactly. Same goes for the sun. It’s more of a reference to Sūryaloka and Candraloka.

Comment: These lokas are beyond our perception. And they don’t exactly refer to the planetary bodies of the same name here. If you want to look at the size of planetary bodies, then go for siddhāntic jyotiṣa śāstras. For e.g. Āryabhaṭīya. It’s mentioned explicitly in Āryabhaṭīya (1.7) that the linear diameter of sun and moon is 4410 & 315 yojanas respectively.

Comment: Can write an answer